# What is the definition of an anti-pattern in the context of java 8 - Streams?

Tags: java

[I'm reading this excellent series of articles about stream.](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2016/dive-into-java-streams-library/)

Can a definition to anti-pattern in the context of java 8 -Stream will be a stream that does not produce a valid result using parrallel and a valid result using sequential calculation?

Example from the article:

A good pattern: (the stream can be calculated sequentaly and in parallel)

```
Set<String> uniqueStrings = strings.stream().collect(
    HashSet::new,
    HashSet::add,
    HashSet::addAll);
```

An anti-pattern: (the stream be calculated only sequentaly and not in parallel)

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
strings.stream().forEach(s -> set.add(s));
```

Comment: see [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)

Comment: hi @gnat , I specified example and my own definition to stream anti pattern. I would like to read more opinitions about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood why this is being called an anti-pattern.

> Can a definition to anti-pattern in the context of java 8 -Stream will be a stream that does not produce a valid result using parrallel and a valid result using sequential calculation?

Not producing a valid result would be a bug.  Not an anti-pattern.

The parallel vs sequential issue is purely about efficiency.  The only way this issue causes a bug is if resources are overwhelmed.

What this is about is writing code that is flexible enough that it can be automatically optimized to take advantage of a parallel environment. The sequential code can't.

There is no such thing as an anti-pattern without context and purpose.  Here that's wanting the code to be able to take advantage of parallelism.  Either code example works just as well on a single core in a single thread.